# How to set disabled status using `SharedPreferences`

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have disabled a `button` using `timer` for 2 minutes.

```
 btn_Verify.setEnabled(false);
 Log.e("LoginActivity", "counter :" + counter);
 Handler h = new Handler();
 h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
        btn_Verify.setEnabled(true);
     }
  },120000);
```

If I exit the app and start again, the `button` will be enabled. So, I have to save it in `SharedPreference` and block it for 2 minutes and then unblock it.
Can anyone show me how to save it in `SharedPreference`.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use a service for that.

Answer (score 0):

This is session store class.

```
public class SessionStore {

    public static boolean button_value = true;

    public static void saveBoolean(Context context, String key, boolean value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(
                STOREPREFF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public static boolean getBoolean(Context context, String key,
            boolean defaultValue) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(
                STOREPREFF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, defaultValue);
    }
```

> then where ever u need to enable or disable the button.U can  save it
>   in session store.

```
For saving
 SessionStore.saveBoolean(getApplicationContext(),
                SessionStore.button_value , "true or false");
For getting 
 SessionStore.getBoolean(getApplicationContext(),
                SessionStore.button_value , "");
```